# Can ansible-vault be used to add new secrets to vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

Form the ansible documentation 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html
It seems we can only encrypt/decrypt files using ansible-vault. Can it not add new secrets to my vault instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove anything in that respective vault file using the `ansible-vault edit file.yml`.
This is already been included in the vault documentation.
Please clarify your question a bit more if this is now what you asked for.